# Store record with relations

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to store a record (user), which has a related class (userprofile). How do I store them in one run? I have tried the following.

```php
public function store(UserRequest $request, User $model)
{
    $model->create($request->merge([
        'picture' => $request->photo ? $request->photo->store('profile', 'public') : null,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->get('password'))
    ])->all());

    $model->userprofile()->create([
        'userprofile_firstname' => 'firstname',
        'userprofile_lastname' => 'lastname',
        'userprofile_phone' => 'phone',
        'userprofile_created' => Carbon::now(),
        'userprofile_createdbyid' => Auth::id(),
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('user.index')->withStatus(__('user added'));
}
```

But this gives me a constraint error because userprofile_userid (which is the ID of the user, and the foreign key relation) is empty.

The relations are configured like this:

```php
public function userprofile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Userprofile::class, 'userprofile_userid');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class);
}
```

Should I, after saving the user, manually look up the user to get its ID? I would assume that Laravel automatically fills in the id since the relations are configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a using create function, it will return the user so you can use it later like this:

```
$user = $model->create($request->merge([
    'picture' => $request->photo ? $request->photo->store('profile', 'public') : null,
    'password' => Hash::make($request->get('password'))
])->all());


$model->userprofile()->create([
    "userprofile_userid" => $user->id,
    "userprofile_firstname" => "firstname",
    "userprofile_lastname" => "lastname",
    "userprofile_phone" => "phone",            
    "userprofile_created" => Carbon::now(),
    "userprofile_createdbyid" => Auth::id(),
]);
```

As per official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserts)

> Once we have made the attributes mass assignable, we can use the create method to insert a new record in the database. The create method returns the saved model instance:

Comment: For some reason that fails with "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'userprofile_userid' cannot be null". If I dd $user->id, I do get the correct id. So I'm quite confused why the SQL statement is inserting NULL

Comment: ok, changing  $model->userprofile()->create([ to $userprofile = $user->userprofile()->create([ did the job. Thanks!!